# Resolving circular shared-object dependencies with ctypes/cffi

Tags: python, ctypes, circular-dependency, dlopen, python-cffi

I would like to use `cffi` (or even `ctypes` if I must) to access a C ABI from Python 3 on Linux. The API is implemented by a number of `.so` files (let's call them `libA.so`, `libB.so` and `libC.so`), such that `libA` contains the main exported functions, and the other libs provide support for `libA`.

Now, `libA` depends on `libB` and `libB` depends on `libC`. However, there's a problem. There's a global array defined by `libA` that `libC` expects to be present. So `libC` actually depends on `libA` - a circular dependency. Trying to use cffi or ctags equivalent to `dlopen` to load `libA` results in missing symbols from `libB` and `libC`, but trying to load `libC` first results in an error about the missing array (which is in `libA`).

Since it's a variable, rather than a function, the RTLD_LAZY option doesn't seem to apply here.

Oddly, `ldd libA.so` doesn't show `libB` or `libC` as dependencies so I'm not sure if that's part of the problem. I suppose that relies on any program that links with these libraries to explicitly specify them all.

Is there a way to get around this? One idea was to create a new shared object (say, "all.so") that is dependent on `libA`, `libB` and `libC` so that `dlopen("all.so")` might load everything it needs in one go, but I can't get this to work either.

What's the best strategy to handle this situation? In reality, the ABI I'm trying to access is pretty large, with perhaps 20-30 shared object files.

Comment: How is the "*static array*" declared? Hopefully, without the `static` keyword.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I guess I meant _global_ - it's declared `extern` by libC, but not `static` in `libA`.

Comment: Of course it's not declared *static* by *libA* (beacauce then *libC* wouldn't "see" it). What doe **global*" mean?

Comment: Uh, not static? :)  I mean it's available to anything that links with `libA` I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (if I understood the problem correctly,) is a perfectly normal usecase on *Nix*, and should run without problems.

When dealing with problems related to *ctypes* ([[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)), the best (generic) way to tackle them is:

- Write a (small) *C* application that does the required job (and of course, works)
- Only then move to *ctypes* (basically this is translating the above application)

I prepared a small (and dummy) example:

- *defines.h*:

  ```c
  #pragma once

  #include <stdio.h>

  #define PRINT_MSG_0() printf("From C: [%s] (%d) - [%s]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
  ```
- ***libC***:

  - *libC.h*:

    ```c
    #pragma once


    size_t funcC();
    ```
  - *libC.c*:

    ```c
    #include "defines.h"
    #include "libC.h"
    #include "libA.h"


    size_t funcC() {
        PRINT_MSG_0();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_DIM; i++)
        {
            printf("%zu - %c\n", i, charArray[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return ARRAY_DIM;
    }
    ```
- ***libB***:

  - *libB.h*:

    ```c
    #pragma once


    size_t funcB();
    ```
  - *libB.c*:

    ```c
    #include "defines.h"
    #include "libB.h"
    #include "libC.h"


    size_t funcB() {
        PRINT_MSG_0();
        return funcC();
    }
    ```
- ***libA***:

  - *libA.h*:

    ```c
    #pragma once

    #define ARRAY_DIM 3


    extern char charArray[ARRAY_DIM];

    size_t funcA();
    ```
  - *libA.c*:

    ```c
    #include "defines.h"
    #include "libA.h"
    #include "libB.h"


    char charArray[ARRAY_DIM] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};


    size_t funcA() {
        PRINT_MSG_0();
        return funcB();
    }
    ```
- *code.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

  import sys
  from ctypes import CDLL, \
      c_size_t


  DLL = "./libA.so"


  def main():
      lib_a = CDLL(DLL)
      func_a = lib_a.funcA
      func_a.restype = c_size_t

      ret = func_a()
      print("{:s} returned {:d}".format(func_a.__name__, ret))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
      main()
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ls
> code.py  defines.h  libA.c  libA.h  libB.c  libB.h  libC.c  libC.h
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o libC.so libC.c
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o libB.so libB.c -L. -lC
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o libA.so libA.c -L. -lB
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ls
> code.py  defines.h  libA.c  libA.h  libA.so  libB.c  libB.h  libB.so  libC.c  libC.h  libC.so
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd libC.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdfb1f4000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f56dcf23000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f56dd4ef000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd libB.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc2e7fd000)
>         libC.so => ./libC.so (0x00007fdc90a9a000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdc906d0000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdc90e9e000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd libA.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd20d53000)
>         libB.so => ./libB.so (0x00007fdbee95a000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdbee590000)
>         libC.so => ./libC.so (0x00007fdbee38e000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdbeed5e000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> nm -S libC.so | grep charArray
>                  U charArray
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> nm -S libA.so | grep charArray
> 0000000000201030 0000000000000003 D charArray
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python3 code.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>
> From C: [libA.c] (9) - [funcA]
> From C: [libB.c] (7) - [funcB]
> From C: [libC.c] (7) - [funcC]
> 0 - A
> 1 - B
> 2 - C
>
> funcA returned 3
> ```

But if your array is declared as *static* ([[CPPReference]: C keywords: static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/static)) (and thus, as a consequence it can't be *extern* as in the example), then you're kind of toasted.

***@EDIT0***: Extending the example so that it better fits the description.

Since *ldd* doesn't show dependencies between the *.so*s, I'm going to assume that each is loaded dynamically.

- *utils.h*:

  ```c
  #pragma once

  #include <dlfcn.h>


  void *loadLib(char id);
  ```
- *utils.c*:

  ```c
  #include "defines.h"
  #include "utils.h"


  void *loadLib(char id) {
      PRINT_MSG_0();
      char libNameFormat[] = "lib%c.so";
      char libName[8];
      sprintf(libName, libNameFormat, id);
      int load_flags = RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL;  // !!! @TODO - @CristiFati: Note RTLD_LAZY: if RTLD_NOW would be here instead, there would be nothing left to do. Same thing if RTLD_GLOBAL wouldn't be specified. !!!
      void *ret = dlopen(libName, load_flags);
      if (ret == NULL) {
          char *err = dlerror();
          printf("Error loading lib (%s): %s\n", libName, (err != NULL) ? err : "(null)");
      }
      return ret;
  }
  ```

Below is a modified version of *libB.c*. Note that **the same pattern should also be applied to the original *libA.c***.

- *libB.c*:

  ```c
  #include "defines.h"
  #include "libB.h"
  #include "libC.h"
  #include "utils.h"


  size_t funcB() {
      PRINT_MSG_0();
      void *mod = loadLib('C');
      size_t ret = funcC();
      dlclose(mod);
      return ret;
  }
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ls
> code.py  defines.h  libA.c  libA.h  libB.c  libB.h  libC.c  libC.h  utils.c  utils.h
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o libC.so libC.c utils.c
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o libB.so libB.c utils.c
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o libA.so libA.c utils.c
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ls
> code.py  defines.h  libA.c  libA.h  libA.so  libB.c  libB.h  libB.so  libC.c  libC.h  libC.so  utils.c  utils.h
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ldd libA.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe5748c000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4d9e3f6000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4d9e9c2000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ldd libB.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe22fe3000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe93ce8a000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe93d456000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> ldd libC.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe85c3000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2d47453000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2d47a1f000)
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> nm -S libC.so | grep charArray
>                  U charArray
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> nm -S libA.so | grep charArray
> 0000000000201060 0000000000000003 D charArray
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python3 code.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code.py", line 22, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "code.py", line 12, in main
>     lib_a = CDLL(DLL)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> OSError: ./libA.so: undefined symbol: funcB
> ```

I believe that this reproduces the problem. Now, if you modify (the 1<sup>st</sup> part of) *code.py* to:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from ctypes import CDLL, \
    RTLD_GLOBAL, \
    c_size_t


RTLD_LAZY = 0x0001

DLL = "./libA.so"


def main():
    lib_a = CDLL(DLL, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL)
    func_a = lib_a.funcA
    func_a.restype = c_size_t

    ret = func_a()
    print("{:s} returned {:d}".format(func_a.__name__, ret))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

you'd get the following **output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q053327620]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python3 code.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>
> From C: [libA.c] (11) - [funcA]
> From C: [utils.c] (6) - [loadLib]
> From C: [libB.c] (8) - [funcB]
> From C: [utils.c] (6) - [loadLib]
> From C: [libC.c] (7) - [funcC]
> 0 - A
> 1 - B
> 2 - C
>
> funcA returned 3
> ```

**Notes**:

- It's very important that in *C* `RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL` are there. if *RTLD_LAZY* is replaced by *RTLD_NOW*, **it won't work**

  - Also, if *RTLD_GLOBAL* isn't specified, it won't work either. I didn't check  whether there are other *RTLD_* flags that could be specified instead of *RTLD_GLOBAL* for things to still work
- Creating that wrapper library that deals with all libraries loading and initialization, would be a good thing (workaround), especially if you plan to use them from multiple places (that way, the whole process would happen in one place only). But, previous bullet **would still apply**
- For some reason, *ctypes* doesn't expose *RTLD_LAZY* (and many other related flags, as a matter of fact). Defining it in the *code.py*, is kind of a workaround, and on different (*Nix*) platforms (flavors), its value might differ

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't mean `static` in that sense, I meant global. My error. I'll edit my question.

Comment: In this example (thank you for putting it together), `ldd` shows the dependencies properly, so dlopening `libA` will result in the whole group of libraries being brought in "at once". For reasons that I don't understand, the libraries I'm actually dealing with (which are not open-source and under NDA so I can't provide details - but the provider is big and won't provide this kind of support to someone like me) don't seem to have their dependencies listed in `ldd`. I'm not sure how this is possible, frankly, but that's how it is. So I have to dlopen each one individually, hence the catch-22.

Comment: One idea I've been pursuing is to create a dummy library that is linked against all of the other libraries (`libA`, `libB`, `libC` in this example) and then try to dlopen that, with the hope that doing so will bring in _all_ of the dependencies as a single group. I haven't got this working yet though because there must be 20 - 30 libraries to deal with.

Comment: I've read  the whole question. Bear in mind that on *Lnx* one can strip *.so*s of their symbol information, (*ldd* will show you squat, but the lib will be loaded and functions from it called).

Comment: Did the last part answer your question?

Comment: To be frank, I'm not 100% sure as it was a few weeks ago and I read a lot of material on the subject. In the end my solution was to build a giant shared object that linked in everything else, consuming any circular dependencies within, which meant that cffi only had to load a single object. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But with/without the "*giant shared object*" things are the same: can the circular dependency chain be "broken" and then all the dependencies resolved? In my answer, (with some restrictions), I showed that it's possible. So, to make my point if things wouldn't be possible from the app, they wouldn't be possible from the wrapper *.so* either, and since they're possible from one, they're also possible from the other, and in this case the whole wrapper *.so* is useless, **unless** (again, as one of the bullets states).,you plan to use this in multiple projects.

Comment: Right - I think the factor in favour of the giant wrapper is that it resolved the circular dependency within the set of all included libraries (which was a variable dependency not a function dependency). I don't really know a lot about this area so I'm mostly just pleased we got it working :)